# Unable to remove duplicates with subquery

Tags: sql, db2

I had a built a query previously that returned zero duplicates until I decided to join in a couple more tables.  Now that I've joined them in, I'm unable to create the desired flag due to duplicates being returned.  I've attached the scenario below as an example.

I only want one occurrence of each reference number (123456789).  I want to create a flag when certain criteria are met.  For example, I want to see when reference numbers for a certain account meet "X", but when I join the table I get every instance of that reference number in the joined table.

```
REFNO       BEG   END   STATUS
123456789   123   456     E
123456789   456   789     E
123456789   789   012     A
```

I want to see all of the REFNO's based on other parameters set in the query, but I want a flag for anything where END = '012'.  I can't left join to the table because I will get all three lines.  If I do an inner join then I just get the 012 lines.  I Tried the code below in my select statement to only pull when that scenario exists, but I'm getting wacky returns and don't know why.  I feel like this should be fairly easy to accomplish, but I can't wrap my head around how to create a flag for just that scenario without getting duplicates or removing results with an inner join.

```
,(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
FROM QW.ABCD Z 
WHERE Z.ABCD = P.ABCD
AND Z.END = '012'
AND Z.TIMESTAMP IS NULL
AND Z.STATUS IN ('A','E'))
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
END)  
AS "FLAG"
```

Please help as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get the flag I want to see.

Comment: case when p.end = '012' then 'Y' else 'N' end ? Or maybe where z.refno = p.refno instead of what you have there?

Comment: I think we need to see your other tables and the complete statement.  What other values do you need from that table?   If you don't have the `012` row, and have multiple others, how do you know which one you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure id DB2 allows this combination of UNION and GROUP BY, but what you want is probably something like this:

```
SELECT 'N' AS FLAG, REF_NO,MIN(BEG),MAX(THEEND) FROM TAB_QW A
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM TAB_QW B WHERE B.REF_NO = A.REF_NO AND B.THEEND = '012')
GROUP BY REF_NO
UNION
SELECT 'Y' AS FLAG, REF_NO,MIN(BEG),MAX(THEEND) FROM TAB_QW C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TAB_QW D WHERE D.REF_NO = C.REF_NO AND D.THEEND = '012')
GROUP BY REF_NO
```